# How to test react functional component async call

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend, react-testing-library

I have a functional component. Inside the component, I have called SpecialistsListService service. The service called the API via Axios. I have to test the ***async function getSpecialistsList and useEffect*** functions but I don't do that anyone helps me to solve the problem. When I used class component I simply call the method like ***await wrapper.instance.getSpecialistsList()*** then check the state but the functional component approach are different I think.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import SpecialistsListService from "../../../services/specialists";
import SpecialistsPageView from "./SpecialistsPageView";
import "./index.scss";

export default function SpecialistsPage() {
  const [specialistsList, setSpecialistsList] = useState([]);
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);

  const specialistsListService = new SpecialistsListService();

  useEffect(() => {
    getSpecialistsList();
  }, []);

  async function getSpecialistsList() {
    const specialistsListData = await specialistsListService.getSpecialistsList();
    setSpecialistsList(specialistsListData);
    setIsLoading(false);
  }

  return (
    <SpecialistsPageView isLoading={isLoading} specialists={specialistsList} />
  );
}
```

Comment: Are you looking forward to test is the state is updated?

Comment: @GokulnathP I have to test the getSpecialistsList function. After calling the function state update then check state update or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Splitting your component into custom hooks and component make your life easier to test and more readable by splitting UI and logic.

The custom hooks will look like this

useSpecialistsList.js

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

const useSpecialistsList = (specialistsListService) => {
  const [specialistsList, setSpecialistsList] = useState([]);
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    getSpecialistsList();
  }, []);

  async function getSpecialistsList() {
    const specialistsListData = await specialistsListService.getSpecialistsList();
    setSpecialistsList(specialistsListData);
    setIsLoading(false);
  }

  return {
    isLoading: isLoading,
    specialistsList: specialistsList
  }
}

export default useSpecialistsList;
```

The component look like this

```
import React from "react";
import SpecialistsListService from "../../../services/specialists";
import SpecialistsPageView from "./SpecialistsPageView";
import useSpecialistsList from "./useSpecialistsList";
import "./index.scss";

export default function SpecialistsPage() {
  const {isLoading, specialistsList} = useSpecialistsList(new SpecialistsListService());

  return (
    <SpecialistsPageView isLoading={isLoading} specialists={specialistsList} />
  );
}
```

Now you can test your hooks using "@testing-library/react-hooks"

Test will look like this

```
import {renderHook} from "@testing-library/react-hooks";
import useSpecialistsList from "./useSpecialistsList";
import SpecialistsListService from "../../../services/specialists";

describe("useSpecialistsList", ()=>{
  
    it('Should return userDetails loading as false', async ()=> {
        const {result, waitForNextUpdate} = renderHook(()=> useSpecialistsList(new SpecialistsListService()));
        
        expect(result.current.isLoading).toEqual(true);

        await waitForNextUpdate();

        expect(result.current.isLoading).toEqual(false);
    });
})
```

Here waitForNextUpdate call the useEffect (Generally update the component)

To read more about testing custom hooks use [this](https://betterprogramming.pub/test-custom-hooks-using-react-hooks-testing-library-a3a37031a9be) like

Comment: Hope it answered your question?

Comment: GokulnathP
test failed.
    TypeError: Cannot read property 'getSpecialistsList' of undefined

Comment: i didn't run it because i don't have full code. Is the code build and run? is only test failing?

Comment: Previously code build and run fine. Your Code builds and runs fine. But the test failed. I want the test to pass. That's the problem.

Comment: Sorry there is problem with test just notiesed, give me a second

Comment: In the test forgot to pass service, so it is throwing error

Comment: @Mamun I tested this code using dummy service, now it is working

Comment: why this error show do you have any idea ====Timed out in waitForNextUpdate after 1000ms===
TypeError: specialistsListService is not a functionJest

Comment: This because the service you are passing take time to return output, always good to mock the service in unit testing.

Comment: Thanks GokulnathP it's working using hook but What is the unit test if I call the showList inside the return; Like ----
const getAllList= () => {
   const [specialistsList, setSpecialistsList] = useState([]);
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);
   const showList = specialistsList.length !== 0 ? 'hello' : 'world';
   return <h1>{showList}</h1>
}

Comment: You have to mock the showList, but the perspective of mocking it or not varies per person. Generally if your service have a db call or api call, mocking is a good approach, in other cases it depends.

Comment: GokulnathP Could you tell me the approach. How to test a function inside a function component.

const parentComponent = () => {
   const [specialistsList, setSpecialistsList] = useState([]);
   const childComponent = specialistsList.length !==0 ? <p>Hello</p> : <p>No Data</p>;

return  {childComponent};
}

Comment: `const parentComponent = () => {
     const [specialistsList, setSpecialistsList] = useState([]); 
     const childComponent = specialistsList.length !==0 ? <p>Hello</p> : <p>No Data</p>; 
return {childComponent}; } 
}`

**Question: How to test childComponent. Inside the childComponent I added a condition**

Comment: You have to simulate some parent behaviour, and based on the return output you can check. Mostly it is good to extract the child as separate component.

Comment: in the code you shared what exactly parentComponent returning? (Parent component output someway depends on the child component, in that way you can test it by simulating the case and check the output)

Comment: But childComponent not covered the quality. Because of childComponent has the condition.